# Rendering fast rotating objects

Tags: rendering

Objects rotating extremely fast seem to almost be invisible the faster they rotate.
See this stack exchange post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201504/why-does-a-moving-fan-seem-transparent).

In my case, I am trying to render an "airplane engine" type fan, and I want it to be somewhat more "invisible" to the camera, the faster it moves.

Here is an image of the current render, the fans are actually spinning at about 10,000 RPM in the virtual world:

[image]
As you can see, the engine fans are very visible, even with motion blur.

How would I be able to make a fast spinning object (the fans) seem invisible (without adding transparency)?

**EDIT**

So actually I realized there was a mistake with the first render, where the engines were not moving as fast as they should. Sorry about the mistake.

Here are two frames, one with motion blur "start at frame" set to 0.01, and the other set to 500% motion blur:

**0.01**
[image]

**5**
[image]

As you can see, there is relatively little difference between the two motion blur settings since the speed of the engines is so high.

Here are my current render settings:
[image]

My shutter curve is also set to smooth.

While the fans look as if they are spinning fast, they do not look transparent, as they should.

Comment: Are you sure you can't get more blur with the Motion Blur settings? Otherwise you can fake the effect with a procedural texture (with a Noise deformed by a spherical Gradient)

Comment: That's definetly possible in both cycles and EEVEE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCsMg.gif. You probbaly have to tweak youre settings. Can you show them?

Comment: To rephrase your reference, the persistence of vision in the eye, or motion blur in a camera, doesn't make fast moving blades more transparent.. it _redistributes_ the opacity / relative brightness they have when they are stationary. If 90% of the view to the background is obscured when the blades are still, then you will never have more than 10% transparency in the blurred image.  (In a camera, there's the extra consideration of strobing.. if the shutter is near in phase with the blades, they may appear to move slowly, backwards or forwards, or remain perfectly still.)

Comment: I agree with @RobinBetts, you can't make them look more transparent than this without "cheating". Your edited results seem good if your aim is realism.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying